# upstart & node.js app "stop: Unknown instance:"

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, upstart

I'm having a bit of trouble with upstart on ubuntu and a node.js app.

Everything was working fine with the upstart script. Start, stopping, status-ing, etc all worked as expected until I deployed new code. The changes weren't reflected in the running app. I reasoned that somehow the new code wasn't being loaded by `stop`ing & `start`ing the app.

I did a manual `kill` on the pid of the running daemon which is where I believe I went awry.

At the present moment, If I `initctl list` I see my app in the list:

```
mynodejs.app stop/waiting
```

When I `start mynodejs.app` it seems to start:

```
mynodejs.app start/running, process 16228
```

But, when try to stop it:

```
stop: Unknown instance:
```

And...

```
status mynodejs.app
mynodejs.app stop/waiting
```

...although the app is up and running.

Comment: You should actually post your answer for this and accept it.

Comment: To add your answer - Lesson learnt: You should not kill processes manually using `kill` when you use upstart.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'll answer my own question...

Restarting the init process cleared everything up.

```
sudo /sbin/telinit q
```

I needed to kill the rogue instance of my app. After that, using `start` and `stop` worked as expected.

Comment: I have the same situation but restarting the init process did not help

Answer (score 1):

Using automatic monitoring -> restart, can resolve this issue.
Setting up [monit](http://mmonit.com/monit/) to do so is described on [howtonode.org](http://howtonode.org/deploying-node-upstart-monit), yet more effectively [here](http://gun.io/blog/tutorial-deploy-node-js-server-with-example/). The comments for the howtonode.org guide I found very useful for other's approach towards setting up Ubuntu with Upstart, alas it's inclusion in this post.